# You can't delete all the rows on the sheet Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to remove empty cells from an entire workbook using this code:

```
//Remove All Empty Rows in the Entire Workbook
function removeEmptyRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var s in allsheets){
var sheet=allsheets[s]
var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows(); 
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
if (maxRows-lastRow != 0){
  sheet.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
    }
  }
}
```

from this post: [Deleting ALL empty rows in a Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386492/deleting-all-empty-rows-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

Problem is I keep getting this error: "Exception: You can't delete all the rows on the sheet."

The workbook has multiple sheets all have data in the top 20 rows as a minimum.

The need for this script comes from a bigger problem of not being able to run an import script because of this error:  "Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells."

Any help would be gratefully received!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just to clean everything it can be done much faster and shorter this way:

```
function removeAllRows() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(s => s.clear());
}
```

You can use `clearContents()` instead of `clear()` if you need to keep formatting.

---

Just in case, if you need to remove all *empty* rows (and keep not empty ones), probably it makes sense don't use the `deleteRows()` since it's slow. You can get values from a sheet as a 2D array, remove 'rows' from the  2D array, and set its values back on the sheet. It can be done this way:

```
function removeEmptyRows() {

  // function to remove all empty lines from a 2D array
  const get_not_empty_rows = (data) => data.filter(row => row.filter(String) != '');

  // function to get a range on the given sheet by the size of a given 2D array
  const get_new_data_range = (s, data) => s.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();

  for (let sheet of sheets) {                          // for every sheet
    let all_rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();   // get 2D array
    let not_empty_rows = get_not_empty_rows(all_rows); // remove empty lines
    if (not_empty_rows.length > 0) {                   // if there are lines
      sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();             // clean the sheet
      get_new_data_range(sheet, not_empty_rows).setValues(not_empty_rows); // set the values
    }
  }
  
}
```

But you need to decide will you remove formatting on the sheets or not. With `deleteRows()` formatting of the rest rows remains intact.

Answer (score 1):

Your function seems to do what you want, and I could only get that error if there was a sheet completely empty. One way to handle that is to add a condition to your IF to see if there's anything in the sheet:

```
function removeEmptyRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets) {
    var sheet = allsheets[s]
    var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow > 0 && maxRows - lastRow != 0) {
      sheet.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
    }
  }
}
```